# How can I reproduce connection timeout in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, c#-4.0, ado.net, sql-server-2008-r2, integration-testing

Because sometimes our app server encounters connection timeouts, we added some code that retries a few times until connection opens. So far instead of testing the real thing we test this logic using a mock object.

Is there any way to set up a realistic automated integration test where we try to connect to SQL Server, encounter a connection timeout, and successfully retry?

Answer (score 0):

If you test environment is a local workstation, plug and un-plug the network cable.  Simple network timeout?

Answer (score 0):

The timeout are mainly caused due to configuration settings. check the server configuration "Remote login timeout" parameter.

Comment: I do see the setting, but how can I use it in automated testing, short of setting up a separate instance that is impossible to connect to?